# Jpa Repository query - java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to model

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

**`Movie`** model :

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private List<MovieCelebrity> movieCelebrities = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters & setters
}
```

**`MovieCelebrity`** model :

```
@Entity
public class MovieCelebrity extends DateAudit {

    private Long id;
    private String characterName;
    private Movie movie;

    // getters & setters
}
```

I want to return the **id**, **name**, **releaseDate** and **characterName** along in the response, something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": Scarface,
    "releaseDate": 1983,
    "characterName": "Tony Montana"
}
```

So i made the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT m.id, m.name, m.releaseDate, mc.characterName FROM Movie m JOIN m.movieCelebrities mc " +
       "WHERE mc.celebrity.id = :id AND mc.role = :role")
Page<Movie> findMoviesByCelebrity(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("role") CelebrityRole role, Pageable pageable);
```

But I'm getting the following error in the response:

> "java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.movies.mmdb.model.Movie"

There's a solution to create a constructor in movie with the parameter i need to return and make a query like:

```
@Query("SELECT new Movie(m.id, m.name, m.releaseDate, mc.characterName) FROM...)
```

But since **characterName** is in different model i can't make such a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the question is about how to do a Projection from a JPA query to a return type with nested values.  This is something that is not really there with JPA queries at the moment.

Besides DTOs, there are projection interfaces in Spring JPA that can actually handle a bit of nesting (see the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.nested)).  These would be a reasonably simple option, but you still can't easily coerce one into a `Movie`.

The main other option at the moment is a `ResultTransformer` back in Hibernate.  For example this could be accessed by using a named JPA query and then dropping back to the Hibernate query API before running it.

This is the declared named query (slightly simplified against the available classes in the samples in the question):

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Movie.byCelebrity", 
    query = "SELECT m.id, m.name, m.releaseDate, mc.characterName FROM Movie m JOIN m.movieCelebrities mc " +
        "WHERE mc.role = :role")
public class Movie {
```

This can then be called with a result transformer like this:

```
    List<Movie> movies = entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("Movie.byCelebrity")
            .setParameter("role", role)
            .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
            .setResultTransformer(new MovieResultTransformer())
            .getResultList();
```

Normally, for a single level query, you can use the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` that comes with Hibernate, but this won't merge or group the results by `Movie`.

Here's an example result transformer to first map the return columns (in the 'tuple' which is a list of result fields), and then merge those by `Movie`:

```
public class MovieResultTransformer
        implements ResultTransformer {
    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple,
            String[] aliases) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId((Long) tuple[0]);
        movie.setName((String) tuple[1]);
        movie.setReleaseDate((Date) tuple[2]);
        MovieCelebrity movieCelebrity = new MovieCelebrity();
        movieCelebrity.setCharacterName((String) tuple[3]);
        movie.getMovieCelebrities().add(movieCelebrity);
        return movie;
    }

    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) {
        Map<Long, Movie> movies = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Object item : collection) {
            Movie movie = (Movie) item;
            Long id = movie.getId();
            Movie existingMovie = movies.get(id);
            if (existingMovie == null)
                movies.put(id, movie);
            else
                existingMovie.getMovieCelebrities()
                        .addAll(movie.getMovieCelebrities());
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(movies.values());
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that `ResultTransformer` was [deprecated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setResultTransformer-org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer-) with Hibernate 5.2, with the wonderful comment in the source: `@todo develop a new approach to result transformers`.

Clearly the area of Projections in JPA is still a bit incomplete.  The suggestion for Hibernate 6 is that they'll switch to a functional interface and lambda style API which would be a great improvement - it would be good to see something similar ripple into JPA.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor expression with NEW can only be used with DTOs (Data Transfer Objects).

But the solution is much simpler. Simply return the movie like:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m JOIN m.movieCelebrities mc " +
       "WHERE mc.celebrity.id = :id AND mc.role = :role")
Page<Movie> findMoviesByCelebrity(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("role") CelebrityRole role, Pageable pageable);
```

Or if you want to use a DTO:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW your.package.MovieDTO(m.id, m.name, m.releaseDate, mc.characterName) FROM Movie m JOIN m.movieCelebrities mc " +
       "WHERE mc.celebrity.id = :id AND mc.role = :role")
Page<MovieDTO> findMoviesByCelebrity(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("role") CelebrityRole role, Pageable pageable);
```

The MovieDTO must have a constructor that takes all the arguments from the query with the matching types.

Comment: this query will create a bit complex response, it's gonna create an object **MovieCelebrity** inside the response with the **characterName** i need. What i want is simple response without **MovieCelebrity** object, only **characterName** in the root response. please see the reponse in the question t know what i want, maybe i'm not making much sense.

Comment: In that case create a DTO class that has a constructor that takes these parameters. I updated my answer

Comment: MovieDTO cannot be cast to Movie.

Comment: I updated the answer. The return value must be MovieDTO instead of Movie

Comment: @Ayoubk, you have one-to-many relationship here between entities, so there are multiple characters you might have. Also it is a best practice in this particular case to have a DTO. If you want to operate with the result list later to do changes in the DB - then please use approach provided by _Omid P_.

Answer (score 0):

create a transient getter method for characterName as follow :

```
public class Movie {
private String name;
@Transient
public String getCharacterName(){
return getMovieCelebrities().iterator().next().getCharacterName();

}
}
```

then use your constructor solution.